# How to maximize performance in social science PhD program?

Tags: phd

I am currently enrolled in a social science (management/information systems) PhD program, and I have spent a lot of time thinking/experimenting with how to maximize my performance. First I tried working 80 hours a week - this led to a hard time focusing, more time spent doing support activities (e.g. reading) rather than core activities (e.g. writing, coding etc.). Now I'm starting to settle more towards a 40-50 hour week that keeps me more energized the hours that I actually work.

I'm wondering, in your experience, what is the optimal balance of work/rest for graduate academic performance in the social sciences? Other factors that stimulate your academic performance?

Comment: I think specifying a general field will help. Answers for big-lab science will be different compared to more individual and theory heavy fields. But most important advice: if it always feels like work then maybe it is not the right job.

Comment: Thanks. That's great feedback. My field is social science, so a lot of alone work, writing is the highest priority. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I too have struggled at times to find this balance.  I'm coming from math and computer science (rather than social science), but I think the field matters less than the type of work.  If what you're trying to do is cognitively intense, then it's really important to be well-rested and to maintain focus.  In grad school, I often would bang my head for hours on problems without much progress.  Now **if I work for 45 minutes or an hour with little progress**, I'll go for a short walk, get a light snack, do jumping jacks, or play a quick web game; all of these are ways to **reset my focus and attention**.

Probably the single **most useful skill I've learned** is to **be more aware of my current state** (energy level, focus, sleepiness, hunger, emotional state) and try to **choose work appropriate for (doable in) that state**.  For more thoughts on this idea, I recommend the advice given by Terry Tao here: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/on-time-management/

Comment: Thanks! That's a great answer. Do you think you could elaborate a bit more on your thinking with regards to taking a whole evenings, weekends, and vacations to rest? What you have described provides great insight into the "micro-cycles" of work and rest, but I'm thinking there are also "macro-cycles".